# Debt Collection on a Lease I never lived

Tags: alabama

my name is Dylan and I’m here because... frankly I’m not that informed in this type of thing. Me and my girlfriend were looking for apartments in our college town Auburn, AL. We were out looking and on our first stop we asked to see the place, etc. We didn’t have IDs, SSN, or anything that was required so we didn’t really expect much other than information on the place. However the agent said he’d be hush about it and show us the place, however we had to have a account with them before we could. We sat down and as we got shown floor plans, he setup us accounts. Most of this he did for us. He asked for my social and ID number, in which I said I didn’t know. He waited a second and said eh, I’ll just put another random clients auto fill saved numbers in there so we can proceed. This was only for me however, my girlfriend had hers memorized and filled it out. Now they knew my girlfriends identity and my name. He continued then to show us the house even though the signs said you couldn’t see houses with a ID which I was surprised about. When we came back he asked if we liked it and explained to us the payment options. They required a co-signer which unfortunately we didn’t have. The only other option was paying first and last months rent up front which I knew we couldn’t do because a month was 1300. But he insisted we could put it on hold and see if we could do it in a month when it became available. (The place was trashed and under construction at the time, so not even available.) We told him maybe we’d have enough saved up by then. At this point, I believe we messed up bad because he actually was tricking us into signing a digital lease on his laptop. I thought we were signing up to be contacted when it was available... We never had to put a down payment, or anything so I thought we were in the clear. A week or so later we find a place a lot cheaper (300 a month), and go all for it. Within the next week were fully moved in and saving money slowly. Months pass by we never get calls, contacted or anything. And 7 months later me and my girlfriend both receive letters in the mail by Alpha Recover Corp saying we both owe 4,025 for this apartment. We called to dispute, and after talking for 30 minutes and being transferred a bunch we told the collector we didn’t owe this and never lived there. She said hold on a moment and when she came back she told us she was going to ask for the move in information from Dwell Student (the apartment company) and that she would call us back. A week has passed by and we’ve heard nothing. I need to know what I should do? I strongly think I don’t owe this money. I’m 20 years old and there’s absolutely no way I’ll be able to pay this off unless I go homeless for the next couple of years. Should I fight this? What options do I have? Should I quickly take all my money and savings out of my bank account into cash? I’m a student and with the corona virus going around right now I’ve been living off unemployment without any support. I understand I should of acted smarted, but it was extremely scam like of this company to do on a uninformed student. Will the court just say being young and a vulnerable target is not a valid excuse? Hopefully someone can help me, it has me extremely stressed.

Comment: This question is a bit hard to follow. You might get better responses if you could state your question more succinctly.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the document you signed on the laptop? Was it actually a lease?

Comment: "Brevity is a great charm of eloquence"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you signed a document without knowing what it was. I would focus on trying to find out if that was actually a lease, and get a copy. Does the collection letter you got say that you signed a lease? If you can give more detail about what that says, you may be able to get more specific advice.

Learn about your rights when dealing with debt collectors and how to deal with them:

- [investopedia - Debt Collection: Know Your Rights](https://www.investopedia.com/financial-edge/0210/debt-collection-know-your-rights.aspx)
- [investopedia - Outfox the Debt Collector's Hounds](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/pf/08/deal-with-debt-collectors.asp)